# Regex - finding last digits from a string

Tags: regex

I've a string that is of the form:

```
 <somedomain>/index.php?attachments/24322
```

I'm required to find out ending number which can have any count of digits after the '/'. That is 24322, in this example. Also, the number will always have 'attachments/' before it. That is, the URL must have the format 'attachments/'

Can someone help me write the regex to achieve this?

I'm still at a beginner with Regex. I'd be using it with preg_match_all in my php code.

Thank you in advance for reading this question and your time.

Comment: You can use this regex `(?<=attachments/)\d+`

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/iPy6av/1

```
$re = '/(\d+)$/';
$str = '<somedomain>/index.php?attachments`enter code here`/24322';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Now loop through the matches array you will get the number.

Answer (score 0):

If the string always ends with `attachments/[digits]` you could use:

[`attachments/\K\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/56ZPVg/1)

That would match

```
attachments # Match attachments
\K          # Reset the starting point of the reported match
\d+         # Match one or more digits
$           # End of the string
```

[Php output test](https://3v4l.org/ureF6)